# How do I solve for unit tangent vector if given a point instead of t-value?

Tags: calculus, vectors

[image]

Here's the mangitude of the derivative $r'(t)$ :$$\sqrt{\left(-23sin\left(t\right)\right)^2+\left(23cos\left(t\right)\right)^2+\left(0\right)^2}=23$$

And then I divided the derivative by the magnitude and got this as my unit tangent vector:
$(−sin(t),cos(t),0)$

Then I plugged the points in. and my final answer is shown in the screenshot. Yet it's still wrong. What seems to be the problem?

I've also tried setting each equal to the point but then there's no solution, for example:

$$-sin(t) = 23$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

What happens when $t=0$?

In fact to get the $t$-values you would solve $23\cos(t)=23$, $23\sin(t)=0$ and get that $t=2n\pi$  for $n\in\mathbb Z$. So choosing $n=0$ gives the integer solution $t=0$.

Comment: AHH i gotchu now. thank you

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with all my questions it means a lot bro.

Comment: You're very welcome! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why did you write $(-\sin(23),1,0)$?  It's $(-\sin t,\cos t,0)$.  At $(23,0,8)$ we have $t=0$.  So we get $T=(0,1,0)$.

Comment: ooooooooooh ok thanks